# Adding a short to a 2D short array element giving error in JAVA

Tags: java

The code below gives the following error :

Error: C:\Users\Laptop\algs4\hello\Main.java:8: possible loss of precision

found   : int

required: short

```
import java.util.* ; 
import java.math.* ; 
import java.io.* ; 
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        short[][] arr = new short[1][2]; 
        short val = 9 ; 
        arr[0][0] = arr[0][0] + val ; 
    }
}
```

But the following gives no error .

```
import java.util.* ; 
import java.math.* ; 
import java.io.* ; 
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        short[][] arr = new short[1][2]; 
        short val = 9 ; 
        arr[0][0] += val ; 
    }
}
```

What maybe the reason for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following:

```
    arr[0][0] = arr[0][0] + val ;
```

both arguments are first promoted to `int`, the addition is carried out, and the result is implicitly narrowed to `short`. This could cause loss of precision, hence the error.

The second version:

```
    arr[0][0] += val ;
```

is [defined by the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) to be equivalent to

```
    arr[0][0] = (short)((int)arr[0][0] + (int)val);
```

In other words, this behaves as if there was an explicit cast, hence no error.

You can achieve the same effect in the first version by adding an explicit cast:

```
arr[0][0] = (short)(arr[0][0] + val);
```

Answer (score 3):

try `arr[0][0] = (short)(arr[0][0] + val);`

with

```
arr[0][0] += val ;
```

the compiler makes the casting for you

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.* ; 
import java.math.* ; 
import java.io.* ; 
public class timous{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        short[][] arr = new short[1][2]; 
        short val = 9 ; 
        arr[0][0] = (short)(arr[0][0] + val) ; 
    }
}
```

This code is not giving any errors. :)